# How to enable PowerTools repository in CentOS 8?

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, repository

Since I had a lot of trouble finding out how to do this anywhere, I'd like to ask,

how do I enable the PowerTools repository in CentOS 8? (equivalent of CodeReady Linux Builder repo in RHEL 8)

Comment: Just for better clarification and context, what would one gain from enabling the PowerTools repository?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can enable it with the following commands:

```
yum install dnf-plugins-core
```

And then:

```
yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

Or:

```
yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
```

You can also just open `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-PowerTools.repo` with a text editor and set `enabled=` to `1` instead of `0`'.

Run `yum repolist` and you'll see it.

EDIT:

The repo is now `powertools` instead of `PowerTools` when enabling it with `yum`. There was a bug so the developers may set it back to what it was before which is why both are listed. The repo file still has the same name.

Comment: Thanks. I found only the `yum config-manager` line was needed in my case.

Comment: Editing `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-PowerTools.repo` is a nice option. Then you don't need to install to `dnf-plugins-core`.

Comment: FYI, this is broken as of today. Need to use "powertools" not "PowerTools". https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=17920

Comment: Note that they may fix the bug I linked and your answer could end up being correct :)

Comment: @AlexHirzel I made a note of this in my edit from a bit ago. Both are now listed.

Comment: I could not make it work with `--set-enabled powertools` and found a comment on this [here](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5417621), saying `powertools` was not an existing repo and suggests to go with `codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms` instead (which worked for me and my current usecase). It's quite intereseting (at least for a rhel novice like myself) to see those conflicting statements on this. And this mentioning here is not the forst appearance of powertools I did encounter, so there must be some meat to it. Or ist his 1 of the differences between `rhel` and it's clones?

Comment: @vrms CentOS and RHEL a two different operating systems despite the former being a derivative of to the latter. I gave another answer either here, Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, or Superuser to use Codeready Builder for RHEL.

Comment: that is slowly sinking in. Thanks for pointing that out once again. It can be quite confusing when it comes to the use of particular repositories and locating particular packages.

Comment: Helped me on centos8 stream

Answer (score 8):

To get more info, run :-

```
yum info epel-release
```

Execute the following command:-

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

enable the PowerTools repository since EPEL packages may depend on packages from it:-

```
sudo yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

You may get an error that read as follows:-

> No such command: config-manager. Please use /usr/bin/yum –help

Run the following command to fix it:

```
sudo yum install 'dnf-command(config-manager)'
```

And re-run the above command again:-

```
sudo yum config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

Now that EPEL repo installed it is time to configure and use it. Hence, run the following command:-

```
sudo yum update
```

List your new repos:-

```
sudo yum repolist
```

Answer (score 3):

On RHEL 8 and Oracle Linux 8 you'd need to

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled ol8_codeready_builder
```

Answer (score 0):

yum config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools

Comment: It looks like you may have the knowledge to provide good Answer here, but please consider reading [How do I write a good Answer?](http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-answer) in our help center and then revise the Answer. Your Commands/Code/Settings may technically be the solution but  some explanation is welcome. Format format commands and code  as "`code`" using [Markdown](https://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or use the formatting options in the edit menu. Thanks in advance. - Also: I'm unclear what your answer is intended to add to the existing answers?