# How can I enable PowerTools repository in RHEL 8?

Tags: linux, redhat, repository, epel

**This is a similar question to:** [How to enable PowerTools repository in CentOS 8?](https://serverfault.com/questions/997896/how-to-enable-powertools-repository-in-centos-8)

I am trying to to setup a headless web server on my EC2 AWS running on RHEL 8.2. As it is a headless server with no GUI, I just need to the firefox browser to do some web configurations. With that said, on on the client side, I am using Putty to SSH to the server remotely and Xming to display the browser. I think PowerTools is needed in order to install `xorg-x11-apps` in RHEL 8.2 in my case to get the display installed in my VM so that I can run my firefox remotely via Putty SSH.

**On the Side note:**

(On Server Side)

1. Installed firefox and prerequisite packages
2. Installed xauth & xorg-x11*
3. Configured /etc/ssh/ssh_config (FowardX11 yes, FowardX11Trusted yes)
4. Configured /etc/ssh/sshd_config (X11Forwarding yes)
5. export DISPLAY=ip:0.0

(On Client Side - PuTTy)

1. Installed and configured XMing
2. SSH with X Forwarding via Putty (With X11Forwarding enabled & X Display Location to :0.0)

**I installed epel:**

```
$ yum install dnf-plugins-core
$ dnf -y install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm
$ yum install epel-release
```

**But when I tried to enable PowerTools, I received the following error:**

```
$ dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools
Error: Unknown repo: 'PowerTools'
```

**When I checked the repo list, no PowerTools is installed:**

```
$ yum repolist
repo id                        repo name
epel                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
rhel-8-appstream-rhui-rpms     Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream from RHUI (RPMs)
rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms        Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS from RHUI (RPMs)
rhui-client-config-server-8    Red Hat Update Infrastructure 3 Client Configuration Server 8
```

How do I go around this so that I can enable PowerTools so that I can run the `dnf config-manager --set-enabled PowerTools` command?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

CentOS and RHEL are actually different, despite one being "clone" of the other.

The canonical name for the repository in question is actually *CodeReady Linux Builder*.
However, it is trademarked, and as such, in CentOS it has a different name - PowerTools.

Since you are using RHEL, you should enable CodeReady Linux Builder repository:

```
subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms
```

According to [this AWS doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-enable-epel/), it can enabled with:

```
sudo dnf config-manager --set-enabled codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-rhui-rpms
```

Comment: This repo probably has a slightly different name in AWS.

Comment: Yes, updated with a reference link.

Comment: You can also add this to OracleLinux8 with:  dnf --enablerepo=ol8_codeready_builder

Answer (score 3):

If you are using the ubi8 container image

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi:latest
```

and you don't have RHEL subscription to enable CodeReady Builder, then your only option is to use the CentOS PowerTools, even though you are on RHEL. In that case

```
RUN dnf -y --setopt=install_weak_deps=False --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install \
      http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-gpg-keys-8-6.el8.noarch.rpm \
      http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/BaseOS/x86_64/os/Packages/centos-stream-repos-8-6.el8.noarch.rpm \
 && dnf -y --setopt=install_weak_deps=False --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install epel-release \
 && dnf config-manager --set-enabled powertools
```

As you can see, installing these repos is essentially turning your system into a CentOS. Given that CentOS Stream is upstream of RHEL, it might make better sense to instead pick packages from a downstream distro such as Alma, Rocky, etc.

Alternatively, you can install dependencies by running `dnf` and then install the needed package from PowerTools from a direct URL. If the PowerTools package does not have other PowerTools dependencies, this is workable. For example

```
RUN curl -Lo ninja.rpm https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/ninja-build/1.10.2/2.el8/x86_64/ninja-build-1.10.2-2.el8.x86_64.rpm
RUN microdnf -y --setopt=install_weak_deps=0 --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install \
    emacs-filesystem \
    python3 \
    vim-filesystem
RUN rpm -iv ninja.rpm
```

Comment: I have a question, how do you find out the URL for a certain package? For example I am trying to install `libev-devel`.

Comment: You could drop the package-specific suffix from the url and you'd get a big page with a listing of all packages, that's at https://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/ Alternatively you can search the CentOS Koji instance at https://cbs.centos.org/koji/, when writing query use percent signs as wildcards, such as `%ninja%`, and you should find build page with the link, e.g. https://cbs.centos.org/koji/buildinfo?buildID=42958

Answer (score -1):

subscription-manager repos --enable codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms

yum repolist
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
repo id                                                                                                        repo name
codeready-builder-for-rhel-8-x86_64-rpms                                                                       Red Hat CodeReady Linux Builder for RHEL 8 x86_64 (RPMs)
copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:group_cloud-init:el-stable                                                      Copr repo for el-stable owned by @cloud-init
docker-ce-nightly                                                                                              Docker CE Nightly - x86_64
docker-ce-stable                                                                                               Docker CE Stable - x86_64
docker-ce-test                                                                                                 Docker CE Test - x86_64
epel                                                                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 8 - x86_64
epel-modular                                                                                                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux Modular 8 - x86_64
ol7_UEKR5                                                                                                      Latest Unbreakable Enterprise Kernel Release 5 for Oracle Linux 8 (x86_64)
ol7_latest                                                                                                     Oracle Linux 8 Latest (x86_64)
ol7_oracle_instantclient                                                                                       Oracle Instant Client for Oracle Linux 8 (x86_64)
rhel-8-for-x86_64-appstream-rpms                                                                               Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - AppStream (RPMs)
rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms                                                                                  Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8 for x86_64 - BaseOS (RPMs)

yum install perl-IPC-Run
Now your able to install it